# AVAudioPlayer Cannot play from url

Tags: ios, xcode, avaudioplayer

I have a small problem - when I try to play audio from my localhost, it crashes.
This is the code, and it constantly crashes.

`stuff` is a dictionary/mutable array of URLs

```
    stuff = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 songlink = [NSURL URLWithString:[stuff objectForKey:@"Link"]];
    NSData *songdata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[stuff objectForKey:@"Link"]]];
    jam = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:songdata error:nil];
    jam.delegate = self;
    [jam play];
```

Comment: 1. This is **unrelated** to Xcode. 2. http://emclstcd.tk

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "valueForKey" instead of objectForKey.

Other things to think about.

Make sure your url has a fully qualified url that starts with http and also, you can not use localhost as a hostname.

You should always use urls like :

```
http://10.10.10.10/mysong.mp3
```

If your url contains space in the name like 'my song.mp3' that is also easy to fix :

```
NSString *stringUrl = [stuff valueForKey:@"Link"];
NSString *newUrl = [stringUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
...[NSURL URLWithString:newUrl]
```